# Using testthat in R. How would I write this test case? Example function with code

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

Here I have a function returning data from a data frame. How would I go about writing a test case using testthat in r to ensure the function is pulling the right things from my data frame ( Sample, total reads, uniquely mapped, etc)

Below is my code for the given function:

```
 get_data_from_multiqc_star <- function(df_multiqc_star){
 df <- df_multiqc_star %>%
mutate(total_mapped = sum(uniquely_mapped, multimapped),
      total_reads_post_trimming  = total_reads,
      frac_uniquely_mapped = round((uniquely_mapped/total_mapped), 4)) %>%
select(Sample,
       total_reads_post_trimming,
       uniquely_mapped,
       frac_uniquely_mapped,
       multimapped,
       total_mapped)
 return(df)
}
```

Comment: this is a pretty broad question, is there something in particular you want to test? share your data frame or a sample of data so we can help

Comment: I want to make sure that when a new data set is added to the data frame, it is tested so that it contains the elements: Sample, total reads, uniquely mapped and the rest that are listed

Comment: basically what I would do is pull your code out from the function and create a second df and test to see if they are equal, just a guess so if you can share data it would help out

Comment: could you try editing/writing the code so I could see what it would look like?

Comment: It's very hard to write sample code when you haven't shared any sample input. Please share a little sample input reproducibly. `dput()` is great for making a copy/pasteable versions of R object, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.